# GET Hierarchical data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I want to get the details of of all child below given child in query
Eg.
 If i give Level 4 or (LEVEL N) then I want to get All Details of all Level (Like L1 to L4/LN)

[image]

Comment: What are the tables/schema? What are you expecting as output?

Comment: i want to all the child when pass the parent id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Found the answer from this Link**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7150#7150)

#### CREATE TABLE:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pctable;
CREATE TABLE pctable
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

#### INSERT QUERY:

```
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) SELECT parent_id+1 FROM pctable;
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) SELECT parent_id+2 FROM pctable;
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) SELECT parent_id+3 FROM pctable;
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) SELECT parent_id+4 FROM pctable;
INSERT INTO pctable (parent_id) SELECT parent_id+5 FROM pctable;
SELECT * FROM pctable;
```

#### CREATE FUNCTION:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `GetFamilyTree1` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GetFamilyTree1` (GivenID INT) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

    DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE queue_length,front_id,pos INT;

    SET rv = '';
    SET queue = GivenID;
    SET queue_length = 1;

    WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
        SET front_id = FORMAT(queue,0);
        IF queue_length = 1 THEN
            SET queue = '';
        ELSE
            SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
            SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
            SET queue = q;
        END IF;
        SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;

        SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
        FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) qc
        FROM pctable WHERE parent_id = front_id) A ;

        IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue_length = 0;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
                SET rv = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN rv;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

#### NOW FIRE SELECT QUERY:

```
SELECT id,GetFamilyTree1(id) FROM pctable where id = 2;
```

****Above Query will give child of id 2.****

After 2 days i got solution.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your nth level query you can do it with SELF JOIN Like

```
SELECT a.name, b.name FROM clildparent a, clildparent b WHERE a.id = b.parent_id;
```

Think it will help !!